# How to pass an argument in a R function that I want to use to make a join

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse

In an R function written with the tidyverse syntax, I would like to pass as argument the name of a variable (without "") that I want to use to make a join.

My example below :
Many thanks in advance !

```
table1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("a","b","c"),
  especes = c("setosa","versicolor","virginica")
)

mafonc <- function(var=NULL) {

  resultat <- iris %>% left_join(table1,
                                 by =  c("Species"=var))
  
  return(resultat)
}

mafonc(var=especes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You would need to use `enquo()` and `as_label()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
table1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("a","b","c"),
  especes = c("setosa","versicolor","virginica")
)

mafonc <- function(var=NULL) {
  
  var <- enquo(var)
  resultat <- iris %>% left_join(table1,
                                 by =  c("Species"=as_label(var)))
  
  return(resultat)
}

mafonc(var=especes)
```

Comment: in this sense it does not work
```
resultat <- table1 %>% left_join(iris,
                                 by =  c(as_label(var)="Species"))
```